# Save all elements of while loop as a vector

Tags: r, while-loop

suppose I run the following code:

```
a=1
while(a<3) {
a= a + rnorm(1)
}
```

I would like to know all the values the variable a has taken before satisfying the while statement, NOT just the evaluation of the last value of a that satisfies the condition. Preferably I would like the outputted elements as a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this should be what you're looking for

```
a=1
c=1
value_vector = NULL
while(a<3) {
  a= a + rnorm(1)
  print(a)
  value_vector[c] <- a 
  c  <- c + 1
}
```

Comment: This answer worked well. The value_vector stored what I needed, so for me, the print(a) part was superfluous.